# Sql Scheduler with asp page triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, scheduler

Forgive me if the question is so simple. As i am new to this i dont know how to do this. I need to create a sql scheduler which will trigger the asp page for every 15 days and sends the design Page as email to the mentioned email id. Please forgive me if the question is not clear. Please provide any example or a link. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a job using SQL Server Agent, and create a single step of type "Operating System (CmdExec)" with the below command.

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://yoursite.com/yourpage.aspx"
```

or 64bit OS

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://yoursite.com/yourpage.aspx"
```